# Изменение высоты XIB контроллера

Tags: xcode, ios, autolayout, objective-c

При инициализации вьюха моего XIB контроллера получает определенные размеры. В нем есть текстовое поле, при печатании текста в котором оно увеличивается в высоту. Под ним еще таблицы, кнопки и прочее, которые смещаются вниз благодаря auto layout.  Однако при смещении вниз сама вьюха контроллера размера своего не меняет. Как сделать так, чтобы он менял свой размер?

**ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ:** В общем, проблема в следующем: даже если все убрать и оставить один лишь UITextView, при вводе туда текста размер его не увеличивается. В чем проблема?

[image]

Comment: Контроллер не имет размера, он же не вьюха.

Comment: @Bimawa исправил.

Comment: @daves, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: Под исправил подразумевал, что учел замечания @Bimawa и исправил вопрос, а проблема так и не решена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, пришлось в делегате  `textViewDidChange` вручную менять размеры `self.view.frame`.

Answer (score 2):

> Однако при смещении вниз сам контроллер размера своего не меняет. Как сделать так, чтобы он менял свой размер?

Пишите вопросы правильно, а то не будете получать ответы, либо, что еще хуже, ответы будут такие же, как и вопросы. Как я и говорил, контроллеры не имеют размеров, это можно узнать из документации: [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html), но ViewController имеет свойство `view`. Собственно, благодаря экстросенсорным способностям, можно предположить, что Вы хотите изменить его размер?
Если же это так и Вы используете автолайауты, то Вам всего-навсего нужно создать `Constraint` между нижней гранью последней вьюхи (если я понял правильно, это текстовое поле) и нижней части виьюхи контроллера, которая, как я опять же догадываюсь, является superview Вашим `UITextField'ам`. Если вы это делается в IB, то обратите внимание на свойство `constant` - оно должно быть равным 0. Таким образом главная вьюха будет расширятся/сужаться (по вертикали) в зависимости от расположения текстового поля. 
P.S. Здесь я исчерпал магию, может, кто еще из ребят поможет?

**UPD**

> ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ: В общем, проблема в следующем: даже если все убрать и оставить один лишь UITextView, при вводе туда текста размер его не увеличивается. В чем проблема?

Подобный вопрос решается установкой свойства:

```
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Если вы установили внутренние констрейны как:

```
    [textView setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];//Понижаем приоритет по горизонтали для хаггинга
    [textView setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    [textView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];//Понижаем приоритет по горизонтали для компрессии, чтобы текстовая вьюха ресайзилась только по вертикали.
    [textView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

В Вашем случае в сторибоардах проверьте констрейны - должны иметь наивысший приоритет 1000.

Comment: Добавил нижний constraint, однако теперь нижняя таблица не сдвигается вниз.

Comment: Простите, но "Без комментариев" :( Надо четко понимать ТЗ, надо четко знать матчасть.

Comment: слегка уточнил свой вопрос

Comment: Ок, обновил.

Comment: Все это установленно, но по-прежнему textView не меняет высоты, а если я уберу bottom space constraint, то поле будет расстягиваться в высоту, так как же сделать так, чтобы self.view.frame также растягивался в высоту, если textView достигнет нижней границы  xib?  
Извините, если так навязчиво.

Comment: Проверьте приоритеты констрейнов.